# Core dump analysis using gdb shows failure in new

Tags: c++, gdb

From the back trace of gdb am getting the below stack trace.
    What might be the reason .
    Is it that new failed to allocate memory or something else.

```
#0  0x00c69eff in raise () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
#1  0x00c6b705 in abort () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
#2  0x005564f7 in __cxa_call_unexpected () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5
#3  0x00556544 in std::terminate () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5
#4  0x005566b6 in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5
#5  0x005568d2 in operator new () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5
#6  0x005569bf in operator new[] () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5
```

Comment: When `new` (or `new[]`) fails to allocate memory it throws an exception, which is what happened here. The hints are the `__cxa_throw` and `std::terminate` calls in the trace. There's no more in the trace further back than the `new[]`? So you know from where the memory allocation happened?

Comment: It is basically called from the below code.char *tmp_p = new char [som_size];

Comment: Use also [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) but do compile *all* your source code with `g++ -Wall -g3`

Comment: I dont have that option right now as this is the core i got from one of my production server and I need to analyse and fix it

Comment: And what is `some_size`? What is its value?

Comment: Not sure about it

Comment: If you use a debug-build of your program with the dump, you can go up the call stack to your code and check it.